# How to run a block of steps on boolean condition in github actions workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to execute multiple steps only if a boolean variable is true. On searching, I found how to run a job or a single step on the basis of boolean condition, but I could not find an example of how to run multiple steps on the basis of a single condition. For example, If I have the following workflow (taken from [here](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/build-and-push-docker-images)).

```
name: ci

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'main'

jobs:
  docker:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      -
        name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      -
        name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v3
      -
        name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3
      -
        name: Login to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v3
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
      -
        name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          tags: user/app:latest
      -
         .....
```

I would like to run a block of two or more steps only if a boolean variable value is true.

```
      -
        name: Login to Docker Hub
        if: ${{ env.IS_CONDITION_MET == 'true' }}
        uses: docker/login-action@v3
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
      -
        name: Build and push
        if: ${{ env.IS_CONDITION_MET == 'true' }}
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          tags: user/app:latest
      -
         .....
```

One way will be to do them individually like below but I dont want to duplicate.

Comment: Move the steps into a single [custom action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/about-custom-actions), and `uses:` that? Otherwise, you can't - it's an array of objects, there's no way to define sub-groups within that to apply the condition to.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [composite action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-action) to wrap all actions you want to put in condition.

In your case it would be

```
name: 'Build and push'
description: 'Build and push Docker image to Docker Hub'
inputs:
  DOCKERHUB_USERNAME:
    description: 'Docker Hub username'
    required: true
  DOCKERHUB_TOKEN:
    description: 'Docker Hub token'
    required: true
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
      - name: Login to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v3
        with:
          username: ${{ inputs.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ inputs.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          tags: user/app:latest
```

and then

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'main'

jobs:
  docker:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v3
      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3

      - id: foo
        uses: ./.github/actions/build-and-push-action
        if: ${{ env.IS_CONDITION_MET == 'true' }}
        with:
          DOCKERHUB_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          DOCKERHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
```

You can keep your action in the same repository or not. It's up to you.